# Why description has <p><br></p> in description by default for some products in stock form odoo 15?

Tags: odoo-15

In Inventory, some products description shows the tag as given in image
by default. Why it shows and how it raised under which condition?
[image: Why it shows tag in description field?]

Comment: This is a bug at the website

Comment: Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: Is this ur website?

Comment: i run odoo 15 addons in local host.

Answer (score 0):

try this changes in your code

`<p><br></p>` replace with `<p><br/></p>`